# Clearance error on pin header solder pads in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, footprint, header, clearance, drc

I am getting a clearance error on the Sullins connector [PPTC191LFBN-RC](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/sullins-connector-solutions/PPTC191LFBN-RC/810157). I got the EDA models from [Octopart](https://octopart.com/pptc191lfbn-rc-sullins-271034). On including this model in my design I am getting a solder pad clearance error on both the JLCPCB design rules check and the Eagle design rules check. I am attaching an image for the same. When I dimension the pitch of the connector in the board window, it comes out to be accurate (or at least approximately accurate).
[image]

I tried checking out the footprint and dimensioning the pitch. It comes to be the exactly accurate of what it should be - 2.54 mm.
[image]

My question is why am I then facing a clearance error? Is it because the solder pads on the footprint are too big? It doesn't seem like that in the footprint viewer. Is there any workaround for this? I cannot find an alternate model for this part anywhere else - I tried [UltraLibrarian](https://www.ultralibrarian.com/) and [SnapEDA](https://www.snapeda.com/home/). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The data sheets shows a drill size of 0.04": -

[image]

Then if you look at your drill hole: -

[image]

... I estimate \$\color{red}{X}\$ to be more like 0.027" and that means a drill hole of about 0.054". Every bit counts so, instead of using a round pad, use an oblong pad so that you can steal a few more thousandths of an inch of clearance.

> *Is there any workaround for this?*

Bite the bullet and modify the library shape. Every pro EE associated with PCB layout have bitten this bullet and never look back to the bad old days of living with what is provided by default library footprints.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your note that it looks different in the footprint viewer and in the board, the issue is likely due to the DRC settings in your PCB design.

In the library you can set the drill size and pad diameter. Likely these are set to sensible values which would give the correct clearance.

However in the DRC settings, there is a [restring parameter](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-restring/) which governs the minimum size of the annulus for a PTH. If this value is set to be larger than the parameters set in the library footprint, the pad diameter in the board will be increased.

By default this restring is set to be a minimum of 10mil (0.254mm) or 25% of the drill diameter (whichever is larger), around the hole. Your drill hole size appears to be 50mil (1.27mm), so 25% would yeild 12.5mil (0.38mm) annulus, or a pad diameter of 75mil (1.9mm) ["restring x 2 + drill"] which should give an acceptable clearance for a 2.54mm pitch.

If however you have used different DRC restring settings, it is possible that the pad could be forced larger and thus cause your clearance issues. You would need to check this yourself or provide the DRC settings to confirm. By a rough guess you either have the restring set to 45% or 22mil.